# Trouble with Mixing Floats and Strings (concatenation error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, floating-point, concatenation

I have a function that will open a file, look for a line in the file, and attempt to replace the voltage in the line for every iteration of my voltage loop I created below the function and I print it for testing purposes.

**I am getting this error:**

> File "test.py", line 23, in
>
> update_code(voltage)
>
> File "test.py", line 11, in update_code
>
> data[i-1]='VINPUT input 0 ' + in +'\n'
>
> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

```
# function required to change the input voltage in the pbit.sp file:

def update_code (vin):
    ff=open("pbit.sp", "r+")
    i=0
    data= ff.readlines()
    for line in data:
        i+=1
        if  'VINPUT' in line:
            data[i-1]='VINPUT input 0 ' + vin +'\n'

    ff.seek(0)
    ff.truncate()
    ff.writelines(data)
    ff.close()


prob=[]

voltages = [0.3, 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.4, 0.42, 0.44, 0.46, 0.48, 0.5]
for voltage in voltages:
    update_code(voltage)
    print(voltage)
```

I am very new to Python, I would love support from the community!

Comment: The error message is quite readable here. It says you can't concatenate str and float objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your float to a string in order to concatenate. Change

```
data[i-1]='VINPUT input 0 ' + vin +'\n'
```

to

```
data[i-1]='VINPUT input 0 ' + str(vin) +'\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says:
`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects`. You've to convert `float` value to `str` before concatenating it.

Modify this line:

```
data[i-1] = 'VINPUT input 0 ' + vin +'\n'
```

to this:

```
data[i-1] = 'VINPUT input 0 ' + str(vin) +'\n'
```